# What does 我为你们践行。translate to?

Tags: translation

What does `我为你们践行。` translate to? I’ve looked around the internet, it seems to mean farewell or to fulfill a promise or send you to the door or practice for you? Not too sure here, please enlighten folks!

Comment: Would it be possible to give some more context please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Judging from the context you may have made a typo. It should be 饯行. 饯行 means to set up a feast to send away someone who is travelling to a place far away. 践行 on the other hand, means to practice, and should not be used here.

Answer (score 1):

我 means I.

In this example, 为 show that the former subject(我) do something for the latter subject(你们).

你們 means you.

Answer (score 1):

Think trisct is right, it should be 饯行:

我们将设宴为他饯行。
We'll give him a farewell dinner.